# Modelling Total Requests received per hour in Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am trying to chart total number of requests each hour with Grafana and Prometheus counters.

So I have a counter which gets incremented at every request `http_requests`.

I am using `increase(http_requests[60m])` to calculate total requests in last 60 minutes from given instant T.

But this is giving me a trend line and I wish to get a histogram.

So for example

10:00-11:00 -  100 (calculated by `counter_value_at_11` - `counter_value_at_10`)

Now lets say current time is 11:30 so I wish to get counts for the bucket 11:00-12:00 by giving me (`count_now - count_at_11`).

1.) Can counters be used to model such data ?

2.) I am open to use other metric types in Prometheus if they support such modelling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For histogram graph you can found it in Visualization -> Draw Modes, there's [Bars toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9J1V.png) that can be activated.

And for bucketing the data for each hour, you can set it in the Query section, by adding Min step value to "1h".

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIGTG.png)

Answer (score 4):

The following PromQL query returns per-hour increase for `http_requests` metric:

```
last_over_time(increase(http_requests[1h])[1h:1h])
```

This query uses [subqueries](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) functionality for wrapping `increase()` function into [last_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#last_over_time) function.

The returned numbers are shifted by one hour in the past, e.g. it shows counter increase for `10:00 - 11:00` during the next hour - `11:00 - 12:00`. This time shift can be removed by adding `offset -1h` to the query:

```
last_over_time(increase(http_requests[1h] offset -1h)[1h:1h])
```

Prometheus doesn't support negative offsets by default, so this query returns `negative offset is disabled, use --enable-feature=promql-negative-offset to enable it` error unless Prometheus runs with `--enable-feature=promql-negative-offset` command-line flag (btw, other Prometheus-like systems such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) support negative offsets out of the box).

Note also that Prometheus has the following issues with `increase()` function:

- The `increase()` over integer counter can return fractional results because of extrapolation. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details.
- The `increase(http_requests[1h])` doesn't take into account counter increase between the last raw sample on the previous hour and the first raw sample on the current hour. See [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) and [this comment](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711) for details. This may result in lower than expected `increase()` results over slow-moving counters.

Both issues are going to be fixed in Prometheus according to [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit). In the mean time other Prometheus-like systems such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) may be used - they are free from these issues.